# MongoDb + Silverlight - [BsonId] assignment

Tags: silverlight, mongodb, poco, mongodb-.net-driver, silverlight-5.0

It seems like the official MongoDB C# driver is not supported in SilverLight. I want to use MongoDB on the server side and communicate the data via WCF to the silverlight client.

The problem is the Id property in my POCO - Since I can't import a non-silverlight project into the silverlight - I can't use `[BsonId]` or `ObjectId` in my POCO which should be used by both the server and the client.

I've seen questions here on SO about having the Id member as string, but represented as `ObjectId` in the DB, but I haven't seen solutions.

What's the best way to have

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

in my class, but still enjoy the benefits of `ObjectId` on the server-side of things?

I've seen [this page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-IdentifyingtheIdfieldorproperty), I tried using `SetIdMember` and `MapIdProperty`, the _id was null on the inserted documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the documentation here for representation options: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-RepresentationSerializationOptions

Alternatively, you could use a Guid in both your code and in the database and not need to do mental translations when querying.

Comment: I tried the way described there to use String and I couldn't make it work - it was always null. I switched to CombGuid and it works. Thank you

Comment: I always use Guids regardless because most of my work requires working with mongodb as well as a relation database like Sql Server.  Using Guids means I don't have to translate identifiers.  Glad it worked out.